# Enabled ciphers on Ubuntu OpenJDK 7

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, java

I wrote the following Java program to dump the enabled ciphers in the JVM:

```
import java.security.KeyStore;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

public class ListCiphers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    throws Exception
    {
        SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");
        // Create an empty TrustManagerFactory to avoid loading default CA
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(ks);
        ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) ctx.getSocketFactory().createSocket("mozilla.org", 443);
        printSupportedCiphers(socket);
        printEnabledCiphers(socket);
    }

    private static void printSupportedCiphers(SSLSocket socket)
    {
        printInfos("Supported cipher suites", socket.getSupportedCipherSuites());
    }

    private static void printEnabledCiphers(SSLSocket socket)
    {
        printInfos("Enabled cipher suites", socket.getEnabledCipherSuites());
    }

    private static void printInfos(String prefix, String[] values)
    {
        System.out.println(prefix + ":");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            System.out.println("  " + values[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run this program on Ubuntu 12.04.3 with openjdk-7-jre/amd64 7u25-2.3.10-1ubuntu0.12.04.2 (/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java) with debugging enabled, I get the following output:

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djavax.net.debug=all ListCiphers
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Supported cipher suites:
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
  SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
  TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Enabled cipher suites:
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
```

I'm finding strange that the debugging logs report that some ciphers are unsupported, but they are still reported in the supported list returned by `getSupportedCiphersSuites()`.

Is there something wrong on my platform?

Comment: Much helped during cipher cracking!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're right and the warning message is not helpful. If you look at the code in `sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl` where it's generated:

```
        for (CipherSuite suite : allowedCipherSuites) {
           /* snip */

            if (suite.isAvailable() &&
                    suite.obsoleted > protocols.min.v &&
                    suite.supported <= protocols.max.v) {
              /* snip */
            } else if (debug != null &&
                    Debug.isOn("sslctx") && Debug.isOn("verbose")) {
                if (suite.obsoleted <= protocols.min.v) {
                    System.out.println(
                        "Ignoring obsoleted cipher suite: " + suite);
                } else if (suite.supported > protocols.max.v) {
                    System.out.println(
                        "Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: " + suite);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(
                        "Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: " + suite);
                }
            }
        }
```

It's looping through the *allowed* cipher suites, not the *supported* ones.

Comment: Thanks! A link to an online version of the latest source would be helpful too to check if the issue has been fixed...