# Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers

Tags: java, cassandra-2.0

We installed Cassandra 2.0 and configure it for SSL, and we run in this issue at startup. We're using Open JDK

```
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55-2.4.7.1.el6_5.x86_64
```

Exception message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support 
    TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers
```

I looked at the following link - but this with Java 6/7.

http://www.pathin.org/tutorials/java-cassandra-cannot-support-tls_rsa_with_aes_256_cbc_sha-with-currently-installed-providers/

Any Ideas ?
Thanks a bunch

Comment: Pls see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34278185/3810374

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming this message is related to the Cassandra SSL/TLS configuration.

The answer [here](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/mina-dev/200611.mbox/%3C5e87acee0611282315oe1938bcqf879d880bc975d49@mail.gmail.com%3E) suggests installing unlimited crypto for your JVM but I believe your version of OpenJDK has this already.

I would suggest experimenting with the accepted **cipher_suites** setting in [cassandra.yaml](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__SecurityProps) to find something that is available to your OpenJDK deployment. [This openjdk question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000020/enabled-ciphers-on-ubuntu-openjdk-7) lists some of the cipher suites that may be enabled in OpenJDK, or you could accept the Cassandra default.

Answer (score 4):

update your JCE files. it will work.

Comment: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226129-Receiving-error-Caused-by-java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-Cannot-support-TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA-with-currently-installed-providers-on-DSE-startup-after-setting-up-client-to-node-encryption

Answer (score 3):

I will try to share my experience having issue with connecting from Devcenter with SSL enabled. .

I was getting the below error in devcenter error log.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA with currently installed providers

In addition to the steps mentioned in http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/how-to-connect-devcenter-to-an-ssl-enabled-cassandra-cluster
regarding JCE files added to …./java../lib/security , I had to add the same jar files to my devcenter installed location:
(please make sure you have the same set of jar files under both locations)

`C:\Program Filles\Java\jre1.8.xxx.xxx\lib\security` and `C:\Program Files\……\DevCenter\jre\lib\security`

That solved my problem..

Comment: Thanks @rraghav for making it easy for us to find a solution. This solved the problem for me at least. Thanks so much for sharing this answer.

Comment: https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226129-Receiving-error-Caused-by-java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-Cannot-support-TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA-with-currently-installed-providers-on-DSE-startup-after-setting-up-client-to-node-encryption